# How to create a connection between Windows service and a Database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, windows-services, sql-server-express

My goal is to have a window service that is running 24/7 that collects all the details I want into database (and sending out alert if required). And another WPF Gui that only needs to load up the data from database whenever the user wants.

I made a windows service and a database with Microsoft SQL express and have added that dataset to my WPF project.

But how do I connect my database with my windows service so that it can collect data 24/7.

I really don't know how to start, thank you for your help!

The others posts that i have seen already have some kind of a connection, i want to know how to start a connection step by step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection between windows service and sql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509522/connection-between-windows-service-and-sql-database)

Comment: @RahulTripathi I have seen the post, but it looks like he already started a connection but has an error. I don't have a connection and try to find how i am supposed to do that.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation page for [`SqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) as seen in the other question?

Answer (score 0):

For make query from windows service to database you can use SqlCommand class.
For getting events from database you need use MSMQ(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx) or use queue in ms sql (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963.aspx) with asynchronous SqlDataReader.

I think it can help you for start.

Best regards